# nodejs and javascript useragent behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I get javascript to pass useragent information (IP address) from the original http request? When I run the code below I always receive the server IP (e.g. 1.2.3.4) address as if it's making the http request.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>ContactForm</title>
<body>
<h1>Contact Form</h1>
<form action="http://1.2.3.4:8080/myaction" method="post" target="_blank">
 Business Name <input type="text" name="businessname"><br>
 User Agent: <input type="text" id="UserAgent" name="useragent">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`
```

node.js Code

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Thank you for your inquiry, someone will contact you shorty.');

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile('/home/ubuntu/index.html');
});

fs.appendFile(timeEntry+'submission.txt',  'useragent='+JSON.stringify(req.headers)+' ', function(err) {
  if (!err) {
      console.log('Wrote agent headers info to file.txt');
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  });
app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});`
```

Comment: I don't see where in your node.js you are getting the user's ip address.

Comment: Sorry, updated node.js to include relevant code

Comment: Worked great, not sure if this is the right question but where can I find documentation on parameter options I have for `(req, res)` ?

Comment: Cool! Take a look here: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req, no better place that official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works for me:

```
app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.ip)
   res.send('Thank you for your inquiry, someone will contact you shorty.');
});
```

Outputs:

```
::ffff:17.###.##.##
```

Worth mentioning that two separate machines (separate IPs) where involved in my setup, only in this case user agent IP is different from server IP address.

If browser (useragent) and node server is the same machine, obviously you are going to get very same IP that is in html `action="http://17.###.##.##:7777/myaction"`

Below content of modified 'server.js' file:

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
fs = require('fs'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'server/public')));

app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.ip)
    res.send('Thank you for your inquiry, someone will contact you shorty.');

    fs.appendFile('submission.txt',  'useragent='+JSON.stringify(req.headers)+' ', function(err) {
      if (!err) {
          console.log('Wrote agent headers info to file.txt');
        } else {
          throw err;
        }
      });
});

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.headers)
    response.sendFile('/index.html');
});

app.listen(7777, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:7777/');
});
```

Result data in `submission.txt` (no user agent IP here, since it is not in `req.headers`):

```
useragent={"host":"17.###.##.##:7777","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","origin":"http://localhost:7777","content-length":"24","connection":"keep-alive","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9","referer":"http://localhost:7777/","accept-language":"en-us","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate"}
```